# ice:inputRichText is not rendered

Tags: jsf, maven

I really dont know how is this possible. It must be a bad configuration... The ice:inputRichText is rendered only after simple forward, but not after form action (h:commandButton). Nothing is rendered and the Firebug says this: ReferenceError: renderEditor is not defined
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

Here is my code:
**home.xhtml**

```
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="index2" value="index2"/>
    </h:form>
```

**index2.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>RDFa test</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body> 
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <ice:inputRichText/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>Impetus</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.dusek</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.dusek</groupId>
<artifactId>Impetus-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Impetus-web</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!--netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dusek</groupId>
        <artifactId>Impetus-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Impetus-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <url>http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/</url>
        <id>icefaces-core</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library ICEfaces Core (3.2.0)</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    
        javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE
        Development
    
    
        javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD
        server
    
    
        javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS
        true
    
    
        org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration
        
    
    
        org.icefaces.ace.gmapKey
        AIzaSyAATyWVqT2qNusNGmcVTyQ0QmymkpU-B5o
    
    
        javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS
        false
    
    
        com.icesoft.faces.gmapKey
        AIzaSyAcAbAa7AL1DLU0785OeWn2byf4XOsm7KM
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        1
    
    
        Resource Servlet
        com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet
        1
    
    
        Faces Servlet
        *.xhtml
    

    
        Resource Servlet
        /xmlhttp/*
    
    
        
            30
        
    
    
        home.xhtml

and **faces-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.1"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>text.labels</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/loggedin.xhtml</to-view-id>  
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>       
            <to-view-id>/logout.xhtml</to-view-id>  
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: "The ice:inputRichText is rendered only after simple forward, but not after form action (h:commandButton).". What does this mean? I assume that you are missing the resources (javascript files) for the rich text editor. In case you are working with Ajax and the editor is not being displayed from the first time the page is accessed, then those resources will be missing in case you "lazy load" it via ajax.

Comment: If I jump to the page with inputRichText by h:link, everything works fine. If I use h:commandButton actiion, nothing is rendered. It really looks like missing js scripts. I dont want to make AJAX action - but it is possible, that JSF do that as an optimalization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution! Thank you very much, noone, you have identified the problem...

ICEfaces adds Ajax capabilities to JSF (even simply adding the icefaces.jar to a JSF application adds Ajax by affecting the necessary changes in the page markup!). The result is that interactions with the components automatically trigger the use of Ajax during form submission.

Here is the whole description: http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Disabling+Ajax
There is also a tutorial, how to manually disable AJAX.

I am really very upset! I have been looking for the solution for 3 days...